# Searching is not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift

The searching in my app is not working properly, the problem is that wen i search for a character by typing specific letters it does not appear in the collectionView, its not reloading the collectionView with the searched items
Here's the whole class code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!

var starWarsArray = [StarWars]()
var searchedCharacters = [StarWars]()

var searching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collection.delegate = self
    collection.dataSource = self

    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done

    parseStarWarsCSV()
}


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        searching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        collection.reloadData()
    } else {
        searching = true
        let lettersInSearch = searchBar.text!.lowercaseString
        searchedCharacters = starWarsArray.filter({$0.name.lowercaseString.containsString(lettersInSearch) != nil})
        collection.reloadData()
    }
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("StarWarsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? StarWarsCell {

        var starWars: StarWars!

        if searching {
            starWars = searchedCharacters[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(starWars)
        }else {
            starWars = starWarsArray[indexPath.row]//grab each item from the array
            cell.configureCell(starWars)
        }
        return cell
    }else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}


func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchedCharacters.count
    }
    return starWarsArray.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(110, 110)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
searchedCharacters = starWarsArray.filter({$0.name.lowerCaseString.containsString(lettersInSearch)})
```

Comment: it's not working. The collectionView does not reload with the searched items

Comment: i've deleted the != nil and now it's working but why? can you explain it please? thanks :)

Comment: because that containsString itself returning bool and you can't compare it with nil

Comment: anytime for any help

Comment: Thanks a lot! really helpful